# Move view with layout constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a UIView with layout constraints, let's say it's like this:

```
███|███ ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯\ 
███|███          \
██▒▒▒██ ← View    > ViewController
███|███          /
███|███         /
███|███ _______/
```

The problem is I want this View to start outside the ViewController and then animate to move to its original position, like this:

```
[1]            [2]            [3]            [4]            [5]
     ▒▒▒             ↓              ↓              ↓
   ███████        ██▒▒▒██        ███↓███        ███↓███        ███|███ 
   ███████        ███████        ██▒▒▒██        ███↓███        ███|███ 
   ███████        ███████        ███████        ██▒▒▒██        ██▒▒▒██ 
   ███████        ███████        ███████        ███████        ███|███ 
   ███████        ███████        ███████        ███████        ███|███ 
   ███████        ███████        ███████        ███████        ███|███
```

In a nutshell, it isn't moving anywhere because of the constraints, but I don't want remove the constraints because everyone's constraints depends on it. What should I do to move it like I want?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what your constraints are (before and after and any other relevant state)?

Comment: this specific view is horizontally centered on ViewController's view and has vertical distance to a view under and to another view above. During this movement, everyone is hidden, if this information helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an outlet to the top constraint. When you want the animation to run, set the top constraint's `constant` to the end value that you want, then, in the animation block, simply call `layoutIfNeeded()`.